# Struts2 preselected checkboxlist

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, checkboxlist

I have tried all the sollutions in similar cases that I found, but with no luck.

My jsp.

```xml
<s:checkboxlist list = "positionsMap"
             listKey = "%{key.toString()}"
           listValue = "%{value}"
                name = "selectedPositions"
               value = "positionName"
               label = "Position" />
```

`positionsMap` is a Hashmap with key `positionId` and value `positionName`.

`selectedPositions` is a list filled with the prechecked positions. Tested with debugger and has the correct value taken from database.
`positions` is a list with id and name.
So my question is how can I show prechecked the checkboxes that are stored in `selectedPositions`.
The result I have is all checkboxes unselected.
If something is not clear please ask me.
Thanks in advance!

More Info from the action:

```
private Object1 object= new Object1();
private List<Position> positionList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Position> selectedPositions = new ArrayList<Position>();
private String positionName = new String();
private Map<Long,String> positionsMap = new HashMap<Long, String>();

//getters, setters

@Inject
transient ObjectDAO objectDAO;
@Inject
transient PositionDAO positionDAO;

public String edit() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);    
    object= objectDAO.listById(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id")));
    positionList = positionDAO.listPositions();
    selectedPositions = object.getPositions();
    for (int i = 0; i < positionList.size(); i++) {
        Position row = (Position) positionList.get(i);
        Long id = row.getPositionId();
        positionName = row.getPositionName();
        positionsMap.put(id, positionName);         
    }       
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seen the code, I'd change strategy: use OGNL's List Projection feature to create a `List<Long>` from the `List<Position>` and then set the key correctly:

```xml
<s:checkboxlist list = "positionsMap"
                name = "selectedPositions"
               value = "selectedPositions.{positionId}"
               label = "Position" />
```

Comment: This is it Andrea! Thanks a lot, I was trying for days and obviously all other answers in similar topics didn't work...

Comment: What about if I want to submit the checked values and save them again to DB? With my initial example I didn't have the prechecked values but when I was checking the positions they were submitted and saved to DB. Now, after your example, I have prechecked positions (that was what I wanted to achieve and of course Andrea you answered my question, but when I click on submit it is not working). If you have any ideas please share them. Thanks!

Comment: Weird, since the only things that matter when sending back to the action are `name` (to target the destination list) and `listKey` (to specify what to send to the destination list), and both have not been changed. Check carefully what you might've done along the way that has broken the thing :>

Comment: To fix the second issue I had to change 'name' with the name of the list `List<Long> positionsSelected` that I use in my save method. So `value = "selectedPositions.{positionId}"` and `name  = "positionsSelected"` will make it work with submit new entries, or edit entries with preselected checkboxes.

Comment: Definitely! The mess of structures obfuscated the simple truth :S BTW, many things could be improved / semplified in the code posted in the answer... I'll be happy to discuss that if you'll ask it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  (similar to stackoverflow but oriented to improve working software, instead of solving blocking problems), if you are interested