# How to default checked values struts 2 checkboxlist with Entity List

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, entity, checkboxlist

I'm trying to defaulted checked some values with struts checkboxlist :

**CheckBoxListAction.class**

```
    public class CheckBoxListAction extends ActionSupport{
         private List<Categories> listCategories;
         private List<Categories> categories;

         public void setListCategories(List<Categories> listCategories) {
              this.listCategories = listCategories;
         }

        public List<Categories> getListCategories() {
             listCategories = new ArrayList<>();
             listCategories.add(new Categories(1, "AAA"));
             listCategories.add(new Categories(2, "BBB"));
             listCategories.add(new Categories(3, "CCC"));
             listCategories.add(new Categories(4, "DDD"));
             return listCategories;
        }

        public List<Categories> getCategories() {
             return categories;
        }

        public void setCategories(List<Categories> categories) {
             this.categories = categories;
        }

        public List<Categories> getDefaultCategories(){
             List<Categories> vList = new ArrayList<>();
             vList.add(new Categories(1, "AAA"));
             vList.add(new Categories(2, "BBB"));
             return vList;
        }

    }
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

   <action name="checkBoxListAction"
         class="demo.example.CheckBoxListAction">
    <result>jsp/page.jsp</result>
   </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

**page.jsp**

```
<s:checkboxlist name="categories" label="Categories"
     list="listCategories" listKey="id" listValue="label" value="defaultCategories"/>
```

Which result with : `[ ]AAA [ ]BBB [ ]CCC [ ]DDD`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="1" id="checkboxlist_categories-1"/>
<label for="checkboxlist_categories-1" class="checkboxLabel">AAA</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="2" id="checkboxlist_categories-2"/>
<label for="checkboxlist_categories-2" class="checkboxLabel">BBB</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="3" id="checkboxlist_categories-3"/>
<label for="checkboxlist_categories-3" class="checkboxLabel">CCC</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="4" id="checkboxlist_categories-4"/>
<label for="checkboxlist_categories-4" class="checkboxLabel">DDD</label>
<input type="hidden" id="__multiselect_customer-categories-new_categories" name="__multiselect_categories" value="" />
```

I expected : `[ X ]AAA [ X ]BBB [ ]CCC [ ]DDD` , but "AAA" and "BBB" are not checked as default values.

I've followed this tutorial : [struts2-checkboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-examples](https://mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/) And check some FAQ in Stack Overflow but can't figure out what's wrong.

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for bad English.

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480893/10606400) answer ?

Comment: Yes, i did but no result

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone for disturbing you,

After many and many attemps, the solution was in the value side and not the Entity.

```
public List<Integer> getDefaultCategories(){
        List<Integer> vInt = new ArrayList<>();
        vInt.add(1);
        vInt.add(2);
        return vInt;
}
```

Thank you for your help.